# Add a variable that changes according to the index in the for loop inside the function as an argument in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, parameters, arguments

In example 2, I want to get a result like in example 1. so I want to add a variable that changes according to the index in the for loop inside the function as an argument to get_tot function.  Is it possible?. Thanks.

```
########## example 1 ##############################
d=list()
for (s in 1 : 5 ) {
d[[s]] <-s
}

get_tot <- function () {
res=list()
for (i in 1 : 5 ) {
res[[i]] <- d[[i]] +10
}
return(res)
}

get_tot()
[[1]]
[1] 11

[[2]]
[1] 12

[[3]]
[1] 13

[[4]]
[1] 14

[[5]]
[1] 15
####################################################

########## example 2 ##############################

d=list()
for (s in 1 : 5 ) {
d[[s]] <-s
}

rm(i)
get_tot <- function (dat) {
res=list()
for (i in 1 : 5 ) {
res[[i]] <- dat +10
}
return(res)
}

get_tot(dat=d[[i]])
Error in get_tot(dat = d[[i]]) : object 'i' not found
```

Comment: Don't you just need `get_tot(d)`?

Comment: You are right but I will use it in a more complex problem. That's why I gave the simple example above. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to tell exactly what you want the output to be from the question, but does this do it:

```r
d=list()
for (s in 1 : 5 ) {
  d[[s]] <-s
}
d
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 5

get_tot <- function (dat) {
    dat +10
}

lapply(d, \(i) get_tot(i))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 11
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 12
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 13
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 14
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 15
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Nice solution. I'm actually going to use it in a different and complex problem. I think your suggestion will work for me. Thank you.